# Remove almost duplicate content in a json file

Tags: bash

I have a json file, and I have lines with almost duplicate content (an array value is added every line) but I only need the last line, with all array values. (3rd line in the example below)

I want to loop through the file and check on the first 100 characters of every line (these are identical among the duplicates), and then only keep the last (complete) line of a set of (almost) duplicates.

almost is very important; I can't use uniq for example, since the lines are not 100% unique (see the element that gets added in media_url)

Example:

```
{"project": {"bodytext": ["long text"], "media": [{"media_url": ["files//1"]}]}, ]},

{"project": {"bodytext": ["long text"], "media": [{"media_url": ["files//1"],["files//2"]}]}, ]},

{"project": {"bodytext": ["long text"], "media": [{"media_url": ["files//1"],["files//2"],["files//3"]}]}, ]}, <- only keep this line
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'd prefer to solve this with a bash script.

Thanks

Comment: i don't think that `bash` is the proper tool for it. use a real programming language (like `python`), parse the json to some data-structure, compare the data-structures and discard those the subsets.

Comment: there's not enough info here to think about making a solution in a shell. If it's as simple as you illustrate, won't `tail -1 jsonFile` do the trick? If not, how can you add some steps so we can duplicate your problem data? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already explained, Bash is not the ideal tool for your problem.

If you want to stick to your approach, you could reverse-sort your file and then instruct `uniq` to compare only the first *n* characters, e.g.:

```
sort -r testfile | uniq -w 60
```

See the `uniq(1)` man page for more information.

Comment: This was a good start! Thanks,
I solved it like this:

tac items.json | sort | uniq -w 150 > tacsorteduniq.json

tac reversed the lines,
sort sorted the lines alphabetically, so they'd be grouped
and then I got the duplicates out with uniq

My first thought was indeed to write a python script but using Bash was more of a challenge. It's good to try different tools, because it forces you to think in other ways.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Did the `tac` actually do a better job in reversing than `sort -r`?

Comment: And if you don't mind, it'd be great if you accept my answer or add your own :-)

Comment: sort -r was giving me unexpected results when the input file changed. Couldn't really figure out what was the problem. tac worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

tac items.json | sort | uniq -w 150 > tacsorteduniq.json

Comment: This works as well, without uniq (the uniq -w command is not available on macintosh)

gtac 23112015.json | sort -k 1,10 -u > 2311sorted.json